# C# Console.ReadLine() asking for an extra input while solving codechef problems

Tags: c#

my question topic may look off but please try to understand my query.
I have a C# code which I am using to solve my problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Chef
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
            {
                String data = Console.ReadLine();
                String output = "";
                if (data.Contains("C") && data.Contains("E") && data.Contains("S"))
                {
                    if (data.LastIndexOf('C') > data.LastIndexOf('E'))
                        output = "no";
                    else if (data.LastIndexOf('E') > data.LastIndexOf('S'))
                        output = "no";
                    else
                        output = "yes";
                }
                else if (data.Contains("C") && data.Contains("E"))
                {
                    if (data.LastIndexOf('C') > data.LastIndexOf('E'))
                        output = "no";
                    else
                        output = "yes";
                }
                else if (data.Contains("E") && data.Contains("S"))
                {
                    if (data.LastIndexOf('E') > data.LastIndexOf('S'))
                        output = "no";
                    else
                        output = "yes";
                }
                else if (data.Contains("C") && data.Contains("S"))
                {
                    if (data.LastIndexOf('C') > data.LastIndexOf('S'))
                        output = "no";
                    else
                        output = "yes";
                }
                else
                    output = "yes";
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program and copy paste the test case input directly it asks for one extra input. Test Case is here

```
5
CES
CS
CCC
SC
ECCC
```

but when I run it line by entering the input it works fine.

For more explanation I have attached an image of running program

The first output shows that I have pasted the whole input as it is and it ran until last test case.

The second output shows after I have given an input like I have hit enter

[image: This output shows that I have pasted the whole input as it is and it ran until last test case]

[image: This output shows after I have given an input like I have hit enter]

I don't know if I have made any sense but if anyone got the same situation or resolved it then please help me.

Comment: If you trace it you will see why..

Comment: Here's what BugFinder means: Put a breakpoint on this line: `int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. Run the program in such a way as to duplicate the problem. Step through each line in the debugger using the F10 key. Use the watch window in Visual Studio to examine all of the variables at each step. At some point, you will discover the problem.

Comment: The loop goes five times because you entered '5' in the input. so the `String data = Console.ReadLine();` line will be called 5 times. then it means that the program will ask you for input 5 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input:

```
5
CES
CS
CCC
SC
ECCC
```

is not followed by a newline. Hence, the console waits for you to hit enter so that it can read the last line.

Comment: Ahh I understood now. Thanks for your answer.